# Matching Input to ArrayList contents

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to loop through an ArrayList contining Football club objects. I am trying to retrieve the name and compare to user input to check if it's a valid team.  When checking, it checks first input (team1) and manages to find out if its in the ArrayList or not but for the second one it does not. Even if (team2) exists in the ArrayList as a valid team, it still says it does not exist

```
 String team1 = userInput.nextLine();

 String team2 = userInput.nextLine();

for(int i =0; i < addStats.size(); i++)
        {
            if(addStats.get(i).getClubName().equals(team1)) {
                for(FootballClub clubs: addStats)
                {
                    if(clubs.getClubName().equals(team2))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(team2 + " is not a valid team");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println(addStats.get(i).getClubName());
                System.out.println(team1 + " is not a valid team");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Learn to debug your code. If the name of the first club in `addStats` does not equal `team1` then your code prints _is not a valid team_ and returns. Note also that there will only ever be exactly **one** iteration of your outer `for` loop. All your conditions contain either `break` or `return`. In fact, on my Eclipse, it tells me that `i++`, in the outer `for` loop is **dead code** which means it will ___never___ be executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Matching user input to data inside ArrayList to confirm if valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048861/java-matching-user-input-to-data-inside-arraylist-to-confirm-if-valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code is failing because it tries to compare the same `FootballClub` to match both `team1` and `team2` which cannot be true unless `team1` is equal to `team2`.

If the task is to verify that the list of `FootballClub` instances contains a club with the given name, a separate simple method should be implemented:

```java
static boolean clubListHasTeam(List<FootballClub> clubs, String team) {
    boolean found = false;

    for (FootballClub club : clubs) {
        if (club.getClubName().equals(team)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Using Java Stream API helps to make this method more concise:

```java
static boolean clubListHasTeam(List<FootballClub> clubs, String team) {
    return clubs.stream()
                .map(FootballClub::getClubName) // stream of the club names
                .anyMatch(team::equals);  // any club name matched the input name
}
```

Usage:

```java
String team1 = userInput.nextLine();
String team2 = userInput.nextLine();
boolean valid = true;

if (!clubListHasTeam(addStats, team1)) {
    System.out.println(team1 + " is invalid");
    valid = false;
}
if (!clubListHasTeam(addStats, team2)) {
    System.out.println(team2 + " is invalid");
    valid = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was incredibly helpful!